# PostgreSQL 10.6_1 Extensions Missing

Tags: postgresql, homebrew, pg

I'm looking for a way around a bug I found with the `OSX` `PostgreSQL 10.6_1` `Extensions` mapping.  Upon update, it misses the new directory for the binaries and the `PG` gem can't find them:

```
2019-02-09 17:48:06 - PG::UndefinedFile - ERROR:  could not access file "$libdir/uuid-ossp": No such file or directory
```

I've filed the bug with `PostgreSQL` but I need a workaround until they fix it.  Anybody have any ideas how I can get this to work?  My app relies on this and a slight version change has halted my work.  Installed with `Homebrew`, contacted the package manager and `PostgreSQL`.

Comment: You wouldn't file a PostgreSQL bug for that, but contact the "homebrew" packagers.

Comment: Yes they have been notified.  I wasn't sure if it was the database or the installation.